# Lost Duration while Debugging Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: debugging, logging, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I'm open to posting the code in this section to work through the optimization but its a bit length and complex, so instead I'm hoping that somebody can assist me with a few debugging questions I have.  My goal is to find out what is causing my Apex CPU Time Limit Exceeded issue.

When using the Debug Log in its basic or normal layout I receive the message

> Maximum CPU Time: 15062 out of 10,000 ** Close to Limit

I've optimized and re-wrote various loops and queries several times now and in each case this number concludes around there which leads me to believe it is lying to me and that my actual usage far exceeds that number.  So on my journey I switched the Log Panels of the Developer Console to Analysis in hopes of isolating exactly what loop, method, or area of the code is giving me a headache.

This leads me to my main question and problem.

> Execution Tree, Performance Tree & Executed Units

All show me that my durations UNDER the 10,000ms allowance.  My largest consumption is 3,556.19ms which is being used by a wrapper class I created and consumed in the constructor method where there is a fair amount of logic that is constructing a fairly complicated wrapper class that spans over 5-7 custom objects.  Still even with those 3,000ms the remainder of the process shows at negligible times bringing my total around 4,000ms.  Again my question is.... Why am I unable to see or find what is consuming all my time?

> Incorrect Iteration Data

In addition to this, on the Performance tree there is a column of data that shows the number of iterations for each method.  I know that my Production Org has 81 objects that would essentially call the constructor for my custom wrapper object.  I.E. my Constructor SHOULD be called 81 times, but instead it is called 32 times.  So my other question is can I rely on the iteration data in the column?  Or because it was iterating so many times does it stop counting at a certain point?  Its possible that one of my objects is corrupted or causing an infinite loop somehow, but I don't want to dig through all the data in search of that conclusion if its a known issue that the iteration data is not accurate anyway.

> System.Debug in the Production org

The Last question is why my System.Debug() lines are not displaying in my Developer Console on the production org.  I've added serveral breadcrumbs throughout the code that would help me isolate just which objects are making it through and which are not, however, I cannot in any layout view system.debug messages outside of my Sandbox.

Sorry for the wealth of questions but I did want to give an honest effort to better understand the debugging process in Salesforce.  If this is a lost cause I'm happy to start sharing some code as well but hopefully some debugging tips can get me to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely your debug log got truncated, see "*Each debug log must be 20 MB or smaller. If it exceeds this amount, you won’t see everything you need.*" in https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_basics_dotnet/debugging_diagnostics
Download the log and search for text similar to "*skipped 123456 bytes of detailed log"* to confirm, some system.debug statements will just not show up.

You might have to fine-tune the log levels (don't log validation rules and workflows? don't log every single variable assignment with "FINE" level etc). You might have to set all flags to NONE, then track only 1 particular class/trigger that you suspect (see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_debug_log_classes.htm&type=5 and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214380/how-are-we-supposed-to-use-debug-logs-for-a-specific-apex-class-only)

If it's truncated it's possible analysis tools give up (I had mixed luck with console to be honest, sometimes https://apextimeline.herokuapp.com/ is great to give overview - but it'll also fail to parse a 20 MB log...

When all else fails you can load up the log into Notepad++ (or any editor of your choice), find lines related to method entry/method exit (you might need a regular expression search), take these filtered lines tor excel, play with "text to columns" and just look at timing manually, see if there's a record that causes the spike. Because it could be #10 that's the problem, the fact it exhausts limits on #32 of 81 doesn't mean much. Search like `[METHOD_ENTRY|METHOD_EXIT]MyTriggerHandler.onBeforeUpdate` could be a good start. But first thing is to make sure log is not truncated.

Comment: As always you have come to save me sir.  Thank you so much.  Yes the log was being truncated and that caused me the largest headache.  When I took the log down to DEBUG levels only then I was able to check my statements.  Which I carefully placed throughout my code to find the culprit.  For some reason I thought I was not seeing the Debug lines of code because i was not seeing ENOUGH Of the log.  It escaped me that it was the finest mode that was actually hurting me in the first place.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help :) yes, it's a nasty "feature" this 20MB limit (they increased it already, used to be much smaller; https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006n4ZAAQ raised 10 years ago, lol. and people still comment). And it's not something you can easily read up before and plan for it, it just hits you, you waste a week and then you remember about it onwards... eh